# Jquery UI objects- can they be made to take multiple configuration objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to make multiple dialogs and with a default object for most common configuration.  Can a configuration object be added in?  I tried and this code fails:

```
var full_dialog = {
    width: "200px",
    height: "300px",
    position: [0,100]
}

$('<div></div>').dialog({
    title: 'Claim# '+ref_num,
    full_dialog
});
```

I've used `$.extend` to concatenate objects, I just wondered if there was a better way.

Comment: `$.extend` is your friend here

Comment: In this case, better = a solution that does not use $.extend that a a comment author feels is superior in their opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `$.extend`, it's simple and clear.

Comment: Good suggestion- it's also very powerful.  I ended up using this after reading more about it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically merge two objects' properties, have a look at this thread's accepted answer: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Then you can do:

```
var full_dialog = {
    width: "200px",
    height: "300px",
    position: [0,100]
}

$('<div></div>').dialog(merge_options({
    title: 'Claim# '+ref_num
},full_dialog));
```